# Ran rake db:seed command without a error; not updating in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, seeding

I seeded the database with no error (sudo rake db:seed). But when I run the server ("localhost:3000/merchants"), none of the seeded information is displayed. Your assistance is appreciated.

Link to git repository: https://github.com/b s h p orkin/Other-Stuff

Comment: your link to github is broken

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
create!
```

instead of create.
 For example

```
MerchantCategory.create!([{name: Faker::Commerce.department}])
```